# Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `m0 Int'

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors, option-type

I am currently struggling to learn Haskell. The following function:

```
findPivot :: [[Double]] -> Int
findPivot matrixA =
    do
        let firstCol = (transpose(matrixA)!!0)
        let maxColValue = maximum firstCol
        let pivotIndex = elemIndex maxColValue firstCol
        return (fromJust(pivotIndex))
```

Is supposed to take a 2D-list of doubles, representing a matrix, and determine which row has the maximum value in the first column. I know there are some inefficient parts, for example using a list for represent the matrix and using transpose, but the problem I am encountering involves the following compiler error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `m0 Int'
In the return type of a call of `return'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: return (fromJust (pivotIndex))
In the expression:
  do { let firstCol = (transpose (matrixA) !! 0);
       let maxColValue = maximum firstCol;
       let pivotIndex = elemIndex maxColValue firstCol;
       return (fromJust (pivotIndex)) }
```

I'm not sure what the `m0` means but I assume it means monadic. So, I think this means that the function is returning a monadic int. Any help in understanding this problem and how to solve it would be immensely appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not the `return` you are looking for.  Hoogling for `return` and study the types should be enlightening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`do` and `return` are related to monads.  When you use them, you tell the compiler that you intend to use monads.

Your function type is non-monadic.  This tells the compiler that you do not intend to use monads.  The compiler is just warning you of this discrepancy.

You can use `let` outside of `do`, but the sytax is a bit different

```
findPivot matrixA = 
            let 
                firstCol = (transpose(matrixA)!!0)
                maxColValue = maximum firstCol
                pivotIndex = elemIndex maxColValue firstCol
            in fromJust(pivotIndex)
```